# What open source software package is available for comprehensive functional, load and performance testing for Java/Grails web application?

Tags: java, performance, grails

I am looking free and open source software that does enterprise class functional, load and performance testing for Java/Grails web application similar to TestMaker.

It should use real browsers for testing and not simulated browsers like HtmlUnit.

The reason I do not like TestMaker is that they have not been able to figure out how to build for 64bit Linux.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand why you need to use real browsers for testing? If you want to record/replay, Selenium maybe a good choice

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at:

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for functional testing.

[jMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) for load and performance testing.

Comment: I am looking for an integrated package like Testmaker as mentioned in the question and not individual pieces.

Comment: In my experience "free" and "open source" tools don't come in "integrated", "comprehensive", "shrink wrapped" distributions.  I don't think you're going find such an animal.